# Do we need any additional setup for REST API Administration Services in MobileFirst?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters, mobilefirst-server

We have logger adapter "WLClientLogReceiver". When we tried to hit the REST service using below link to get adapter details we got 404 error

```
 https://example.com/worklightadmin/management-apis/1.0/runtimes/myruntimename/adapters/WLClientLogReceiver


    Respnse:
    <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
    <html><head>
    <title>404 Not Found</title>
    </head><body>
    <h1>Not Found</h1>
    <p>The requested URL /worklightadmin/management-apis/1.0/runtimes/myruntimename/adapters/WLClientLogReceiver was not found on this server.</p>
    <hr>
    <address>IBM_HTTP_Server at example.com Port 443</address>
    </body></html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 404 seems to suggest the URL is wrong. If the URL were indeed proper , then a message such as - " The adapter \"WLClientLogReceiver\" of the runtime \"yourruntime\" does not exist in the MobileFirst administration database" is returned, in case you query for a missing adapter.

To test:

a) 
The URL - "https://example.com/worklightadmin/management-apis/1.0/runtimes/myruntimename/adapters?" returns metadata of all deployed adapters.

Check if you get the list of all adapters and see if WLClientLogReceiver is in the list.

b) If that also gives you a 404 :

If you are deployed on a standalone server, your admin context might be different - for standalone servers ,it is by default "wladmin" as opposed to "worklightadmin" in the Development server. Verify your context root.

Comment: Thank, replacing worklightadmin with wladmin solved the problem